# i would like to know how long it will take me to mine 1 bitcoin with a 12 th/s mining rig

Tags: mining-profitability, hashpower

I am going to start mining bitcoin.  I plan to use 6 antminer s4.  that would give me 12 th/s.  with this set up how long would it take me to mine one bitcoin?

Answer (score 1):

It will take about a week.

You can use a calculator like this one.

https://alloscomp.com/bitcoin/calculator